# Can't locate the AutoDiscover service when running Outlook app from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, outlook-web-app

I am new in Office Apps. I just want to create a hello world in Outlook Web App (OWA). I've created a new Project in VS2013. *File -> New Project -> Apps for Office -> Mail.*  When I want to debug I get the following exception:

> The AutoDiscover service couldn't be located.

Do I have to configure in Visual Studio the IP Address of my Exchange Server?
Can I debug without the AutoDiscover service ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should register with your Exchange server.

When you hit `Debug`, it will show a screen to you where you specify the Exchange server. You need that since it installs the app in Exchange and executes it from there. Your app won't run without it.

So the bottom-line is: you need a working Exchange server with AutoDiscovery on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But where can I configure or enter the IP Address of my Exchange Server? When i press debug I am only requested to enter my email address an my password.

Comment: It will go from there. If your email address is an Office 265 address, it will deploy to there. If not, it will go to your own Exchange server and will probably ask you for the URL of it.

Comment: I just have a exchange server without office 365. When I press debug and enter my credentials, i get the following exception : The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

Comment: Then there is some config to be done on the Exchange server. (What version of Exchange are you running btw?)

Comment: My current version is : Exchange 2013.

Comment: See http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-external-and-internal-url-in-exchange-2013/, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998601(v=exchg.150).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529912(v=exchg.150).aspx.